# load two files in the same DB table with Azure Data Flow

Tags: sql, azure, azure-data-factory

How can i Load two files(csv) the same shemas into my sqlDatabase with AzureDatafactory flow?

I've created one flow with two input and the same output but i get just the one table data the other one (NULL) .

Comment: Do you mean the data from other csv file are inserted to the Sink table as 'NULL' or the data are not copyed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said, the two csv file have the same schema, you could put them in same folder or container, make sure the container or folder only have the two files.

Then you could follow my steps:

**My Container** :

[image]

**Data and file schema**:
[image]

**Data FLOW Source dataset settings:**

Just choose the container or folder, all the csv files in it will be chosen. When we preview  data, the data of the two csv files will be merged together
[image]

[image]

**Sink dataset settings and data preview(the data will be inserted to the Sink table):**
[image]

[image]

**Run the pipeline:**

[image]

**Check the data in Sink table:**

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thnks LOOOOOOT :D